# Cannot find symbol getWidth and getHeight in GLAutoDrawable in JOGL

Tags: jogl

I just checked out the newest JOGL from git://jogamp.org/srv/scm/jogl.git and installed it.

The installation seems ok. I did run "ant junit.run" and saw 3d graphics.

However, when I tried to compile some example code, I kept getting errors about GLAutoDrawable. It says:

```
  symbol:   method getHeight()
  location: variable glautodrawable of type GLAutoDrawable
```

I'm running RHDL 6.5:

```
$ lsb_release 
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
$ uname -a
Linux oc5088881832.ibm.com 2.6.32-431.21.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 3 19:11:40 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is my java version:java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"

```
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.7.1.el6_5-x86_64 u55-b13)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

And this is my classpath:

```
# For JOGL
export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/JOGL/gluegen/build/gluegen-rt.jar:$CLASSPATH
export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/JOGL/jogl/build/jar/jogl-all.jar:$CLASSPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/JOGL/jogl/build/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

For your reference, I am compiling this example:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_Java_Web_Start

It seems like either I missed something in my classpath or this version of JOGL didn't implement getWidth in GLAutoDrawable...

Please can someone let me know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLDrawable.getWidth() and GLDrawable.getHeight() have been renamed GLDrawable.getSurfaceWidth() and GLDrawable.getSurfaceHeight() [when adding the support of HiDPI](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/commit/ebe980ad6ac40148bc84913d1ba1f7adf6200490): [GLDrawable.java](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/master/src/jogl/classes/javax/media/opengl/GLDrawable.java)

GLAutoDrawable extends GLDrawable. Please rather post your questions about JOGL on [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org/). Best regards.

Comment: Exactly. Solved my problem. Thanks. Next time I will post on the forum first.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept my answer so that anybody having the same problem immediately knows what to do without having to read your comment above.

Comment: Please refrain from trying to divert others to other sites in a broad manner to drive traffic as SO is a place for users to come together to ask/answer related questions alongside a broad range of categories.

Comment: @SpicyWeenie I like SO but when it deals with JOGL, there are several problems. At first, there are a very few JogAmp (JOGL, JOAL, JOCL, ...) maintainers and users who spend some time to answer the questions here. Multiplying the place in which you can get support isn't good, we can't be everywhere. Secondly, some SO users who already bother us elsewhere frequently advertise their competitor(s) even though it has nothing to do with the questions which is very annoying. Using our official forum solves these issues and that's the same for OpenGL, better use the OpenGL section of gamedev.net.